# What is the cause here because I have null error? LINQ LeftJoin Problems

Tags: c#, linq

```
var allCustomers = customers.GroupJoin(packages,
    customers => customers.PackId,
    packages => packages.PackId,
    (customers, packages) => new { customers, packages })
    .SelectMany(y => y.packages.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (x, y) => new { CustId = x.customers.CustomerId, PackId = y.PackId }).ToList();
```

I tried to DO left join operation, but without success

Comment: What do you mean you have a "null error"? You need to exactly describe the error you're receiving.

Comment: [mre] is needed there. We don"'t need real data or real table just enought to reproduce the issue. 2 list of object with bogus property that reproduce the issue.

Comment: y is null on runtime!

Comment: We need to see the complete exception with the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `DefaultIfEmpty()` call. If a `Customer` has no related `Package`, the `packages` collection would be empty. Calling `DefaultIfEmpty()` returns a `default` (`null`) package object for empty `packages` collections. That means, in the call to `SelectMany` you can get `null`s for `y` in the last parameter of `SelectMany`. To overcome this, you can use [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)  (`?.`):

```
var allCustomers = customers
    .GroupJoin(
        packages,
        customer => customer.PackId,
        packages => packages.PackId,
        (customer, packages) => new { customer, packages })
    .SelectMany(
        y => y.packages.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new { CustId = x.customer.CustomerId, PackId = y?.PackId })
    .ToList();
```

You should also note that in this case `PackId` in the resulting collection is a nullable type (maybe `int?`) and is null for some resulting items.

**Advice:** The query syntax is much simpler for such cases:

```
var allCustomer =
    (from customer in customers
     join package in packages on customer.PackId equals package.PackId into g
     from package in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new { CustId = customer.CustomerId, PackId = package?.PackId })
    .ToList();
```

**Another note:** If you write such a query against `IQueryable` collections coming from an ORM (Entity Framework, for example), you will not get a `NullReferenceException`. Because your query is translated to SQL and is run on your DBMS.